# Finding intersection of two curves for an area-between-curves problem

Tags: calculus, integration, area, transcendental-equations

The question is to find the area enclosed in the first quadrant bounded by the line $y=\ln x$ , the line $x=2$, the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and the x-axis.

I have drawn a rough sketch. I am unable to find (without using a computer), the intersection point of  $y=\ln x$ and the curve the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

[image: Text]

Is there a way to find the intersection? Or is there another way to solve the problem without using the intersection of the aforementioned curves?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to solve your problem algebraically.

Comment: Let $\bar{x}$ be the projection on the $x$-axis of the point where the two curves meet. Compute the definite integrals and write the area in terms of $\bar{x}$.